# ElasticSearch in Docker Compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

Please go easy on me here, My experience with ElasticSearch is pretty much solely with use of SearchKick and my own Rails app.

I have a Rails app which I have been running locally on my machine using SearchKick and ElasticSearch for quite some time now.

Recently I’ve been reading about how to convert my dev environment into a Dockerised form.

I have got my Rails app and its database working nicely but then I came to add Search back in .

My Docker Compose file is below:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    app:
        build: .
        command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
        volumes:
            - .:/app
            - bundle-volume:/usr/local/bundle
            - yarn-volume:/app/node_modules
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        depends_on:
            - db
            - search
    db:
        image: 'postgres:9.6'
        env_file:
            - .env.development
        volumes:
            - db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        # environment:
        #     - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    search:
        image: 'elasticsearch'
        env_file:
            - .env.development
        volumes:
            - 'search-volume:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data'
        ports:
            - '9200:9200'
volumes:
    bundle-volume:
    yarn-volume:
    db-volume:
    search-volume:
```

When I start the container and head to the Rails console to try and run `<Model>.reindex` I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): 1: from (irb):1
> Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Failed to open TCP connection to
> localhost:9200 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for
> “localhost” port 9200))

I have set an Environment var like so in my `.env.development` file:

`ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://search:9200`

The error shows it’s trying to connect to localhost which is exactly where I think the issue lays.

It doesn’t look like the variable i’m setting in my .env.development file is being used in the way it should be.

Anyone with an in-depth knowledge of Docker able to help me out here?

Thanks,
Neil

EDIT:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.5

# Install 3rd party dependencies.
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add && \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
    apt update && \
    apt -y install nodejs \
    yarn \
    build-essential \
    libpq-dev

# Sets Environment variables
ENV RAILS_ROOT /app
ENV PORT 3000

# Working directory.
RUN mkdir $RAILS_ROOT
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT

# Script run when container first starts.
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

bundle install
yarn install --check-files --frozen-lockfile

# Remove a potentially pre-existing server.pid for Rails.
rm -f /app/tmp/pids/server.pid

# Run the command.
exec "$@"
```

.env:
ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://search:9200

```
DATABASE_HOST=db
DATABASE_USER=postgres
DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres
DATABASE_NAME=mysite_development
DATABASE_PORT=5432
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.3'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 1.2.3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.3.5'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 6.x'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbo-rails', '~> 0.5.11'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
gem 'redis', '~> 4'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

gem 'devise' # Authorisation and Authentication
gem 'httparty' # Make HTTP requests
gem 'searchkick', '~> 4.5.0' # ElasticSearch searching
gem 'geocoder' # Allows models to have a location
gem 'gretel' #Breadcrumb functionality
gem 'nav_lynx' # Navigation links
gem 'inline_svg', '~> 1.7.2' # Inlines SVG files
gem 'flickraw' # Integration with the Flickr API
gem 'countries', require: 'countries/global' # Country list (with helper to omit ISO3166:: module prefix)
gem 'kaminari' # Pagination
gem 'flutie' # Utility classes
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 7.0.0' # Tagging
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.4'
gem 'acts_as_list' # Ordering
gem 'delayed_job_active_record' # Background Jobs
gem 'foreman'
gem 'daemons'
gem 'delayed_job_web'
gem 'activerecord-hierarchical_query', '~> 1.3.0'
gem 'roo', '~> 2.8.3'
gem 'faker'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem "bullet"
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.4'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.11'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.4'
gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.2.0'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.4'

gem 'ed25519'
gem 'bcrypt_pbkdf'
gem 'rubocop', require: false
gem 'rubocop-rails', require: false
```

EDIT 2:

Latest error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last): 1: from (irb):1
> Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Failed to open TCP connection to
> search:9200 (getaddrinfo: No address associated with hostname))

EDIT 3:

So, after getting my machine back today, I tried your suggestions. It turns out the `search` container was erroring. The error is pasted below:

> search_1  | [2021-08-04T20:44:40,178][WARN
> ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [unknown] uncaught
> exception in thread [main] search_1  |
> org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException:
> ElasticsearchException[java.io.IOException: failed to read [id:7,
> file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/_state/node-7.st]]; nested:
> IOException[failed to read [id:7,
> file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/_state/node-7.st]]; nested:
> XContentParseException[[-1:36] [node_meta_data] unknown field
> [node_version], parser not found];

It looks like it's failing due to the location the Volume is set to.  I temporarily commented out the Volume configuration for that service and my Rails model now gets indexed.

I'm assuming now though, that if I close the container and start it up again that the Index will have been removed because it's no longer stored in a Volume?

Any ideas how I can get the index data stored in a volume and let the container work?

Comment: Your are not loading `.env.development` into your `app` container

Comment: @Zeitounator Good spot!  Just added that but it doesn't appear to make any difference. Can you spot anything else that is incorrect?

Comment: Surely not without you sharing your Dockerfile and a bit of background on how your ruby app is suppose to pick up that environment variable.

Comment: @Zeitounator Apologies!  I've updated my OP with extra files that hopefully will help!

Comment: Also, the error is now showing as "Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Failed to open TCP connection to search:9200 (getaddrinfo: No address associated with hostname))"     So it may be picking up the ENV variable but just unable to connect for some reason.

Comment: With your current reputation score, I should not have to recall you this kind of info should go in an edit to your question rather than a comment. Did you check that the `search` container is not dead ?

Comment: @Zeitounator I've moved that into an edit to the OP.   Can you clarify what you mean by "dead". I'm not sure I understand. I have removed all the containers and rebuilt them though to no avail.

Comment: `docker-compose ps` <= is the `search` container running? If not, it does not have a name pointing to an ip and other containers will report a name not found error when trying to access it. In such case `docker-compose logs search` should probably give you a hint why it crashed.

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, my laptop had to be sent away for repair yesterday. As soon as I receive it back, I shall test out your suggestion and reply here.

Comment: @Zeitounator I've added a new edit at the bottom of my original post.  Would it be ok for you to take a look?  Thanks for your help with this, it really is appreciated!

Comment: This looks like a file nous issue inside your volume. Delete it and start over. Of this doesn't fix, I'd bet this is covered in the image documentation

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks. Removing the search volume appears to have resolved it.  I also noticed I had single quotes around my volume config in my `docker-compose` file which I removed so I guess that also helped. (possibly).  Thanks again!

Comment: Single quotes have nothing to do with your problem. The resulting string to configure the volume is identical: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/